# Why is int32_t aliased to int in stdint.h?

Tags: c

In my Linux VM, even iwth `int32_t`, if I assign it different values, it gives different size. For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t i = 0x123456;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

`objdump` reports `i` only takes 3 bytes:

```
Disassembly of section .data:

0804a010 <__data_start>:
 804a010:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
        ...

0804a014 <__dso_handle>:
 804a014:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
        ...

0804a018 <i>:
 804a018:       56                      push   %esi
 804a019:       34 12                   xor    $0x12,%al
        ...
```

Looking at `stdint.h`, I found out that `int32_t` is just a typedef to `int`:

```
typedef int         int32_t;
```

I though that C99 standard enforces that `int32_t` is guaranteed to be exactly 4 bytes?

Comment: I get four bytes (gcc in RHEL6). I compiled with `gcc -c -std=c99 a.c -o a.o` and displayed using `objdump -D a.o`. Result was: `0000000000000000 <i>:
   0:   78 56                   js     58 <i+0x58>
   2:   34 12                   xor    $0x12,%al
`

Comment: The typedef is fine, `stdint.h` is shipped with the compiler, so it knows that `int` is 4 bytes for your compiler. I too get the same result of @KlasLindbäck, both in 32 bit and 64 bit mode and at various optimization levels. How are you compiling? What `objdump` parameters are you using? What do you get if you do `objdump -t a.out | grep "[.]data.*\<i\>"`?

Comment: Sorry the value is supposed to be `int i = 0x123456` , so the value is only 3 bytes. I expected gcc to generate something like `56 34 12 00`.

Comment: The C standard enforces `int32_t` to be 32 bits when observed from the running program, not necessarily an external tool. Try `sizeof` and see if you gives a reasonable result. Try creating an array and see if the pointer arithmetic matches that of a 32-bit type.

Comment: `objdump -t a.out` reports that `i` takes 4 bytes. I realize it now. This is just presentation problem, since `i` starts at `804a018h`, and the subsequent two bytes starting at `804a019h`. What I wasn't clear is the `...`. After searching a bit, the dots represent information with only zeros, which means that last byte is hidden.

Comment: @Amumu: you can actually make it show the zeroes in full with the `-z` option.

Comment: This is crossing abstraction layers. C only has to do 4 bytes when there is actual input or output. How the program is implemented internally is abstract. The int could be anything in machine code. All that matters is sizeof int will be 4 etc.

Answer (score 2):

C (like C++) has something called the "as-if" rule. From the language perspective, things just have to appear *as if* they obey the C rules, even if the actual binary does not.

In particular, `sizeof(int32_t)` is most important for things like `malloc(100*sizeof(int32_t))`, where you'd definitely want 400 bytes. (Or 200 bytes, when bytes are 16 bits).

In this simple case however, you can't detect the "missing" byte by any standard method, so this is legal.

Comment: The principle is correct, but actually this is just a presentation problem from `objdump`; the executable `.data` section is mapped straight in memory (in COW or similar), so a dubious `.data` optimization where globals with smaller initializers take less executable space would be quite complicated (and probably not worth) to implement (if you are after this kind of size problems you are probably just going to upx the whole thing).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I could imagine an optimization where 64 and 32 bit variables could have 32,16 or 8 bit initializers.

Comment: Well, then you wouldn't find them in `.data` section of an ELF executable, the compiler would probably have to put them into `.bss` and have some startup code to initialize them from `.rodata`. Just to say, I don't think that such optimization could be compatible with what OP saw.